# How to active and Inactive flow using sfdx?

Tags: visual-workflow, lightning-flow-builder

I want to active and deactivate flow using sfdx for all flows as well as specific flow

you can see the below image for active/deactive

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please [edit] the question to add detail around what you've tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: In general, `sfdx` almost exclusively uses `-s` and `--someParameter` notation for parameters. This is true for `force:data:record:update` as well. In addition, `force:data:record:update` doesn't use a SOQL query directly, but instead allows you to select a record with `-w`. In addition, parameters with spaces in them must be quoted in PowerShell. Also, `force:data:record:update` only deals with *data* records, not *metadata* records.

Comment: Hey Rohit, is there any luck with this? or workaround.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, You would need to manually change [< status >](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm) attribute(Active,  Draft/Obsolete - In the UI, this status appears as Inactive) and deploy the flow metadata.  However you cannot directly [Activate/Deactivate flows](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdfSDUAZ/activatedeactivate-flows-via-metadata-api) using metadata API.